# Magento 2 - Adding Product Attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

Since I am just adding a product attribute which is stored in EAV tables, this is how **InstallData.php** looks like

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'customer_product_points',
            [
                'type' => 'decimal',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Customer Product Points',
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Executing `php magento setup:upgrade` I was able to see new attribute in the system.

But the attribute is not visible while adding a new product. Have I missed anything here ? I need to add points to products and same will be reflected on frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add attribute in default attribute set. You can use `\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::addAttributeToGroup` for this

```
       $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            $entityTypeId,
            $attributeSetId,
            $groups[$attributeProp['group']]['id'],
            $attributeCode,
            $attributeProp['sort']
        );
```

Comment: Also what about the variables like `$entityTypeId, $attributeSetId,$attributeProp['sort']` ? Where do I specify them ?

Comment: Please read documentation to addAttributeToGroup method

Comment: You can add it to general by adding `'group' => 'General',` in the `addAttribute` method call. Magento will do the grunt work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would add it to the default attributset, with a group name you can define (or you use an existing group name, like *Product Details*):

```
$attributeGroup = 'My Group Name'; // the group doesn't need to exist

$attributeCode = 'customer_product_points'; // or whatever attribute you want to add

$entityTypeId = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE
);

$attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

$eavSetup->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroup, $attributeCode);
```

Another option would be to add `'groups' => 'my group name'` to your attribute array, it would then automatically be added to **all** attributsets.